# 30H interrupt gives wrong DOS version

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I am running a 32-bit copy of Windows 8 on a 64-bit AMD processor.  I am taking an 8086 assembly course and the book gives an example of how to obtain DOS's version number.  When I start cmd.exe, it tells me at the top that it is version 6.2.9200.  Also, when I run the "VER" DOS command it tells me the same thing.  However, when I execute a 30H interrupt routine to obtain the DOS version number, it tells me I am running DOS Version 5.0.  What could explain this difference?

By the way, I assembled the code below in MASM6 using the command `ML /Fl DOSVER.ASM`.

```
   .MODEL SMALL
   .DATA
   VNS    DB  'DOS Version $'

   .CODE
   .STARTUP
   LEA   DX,VNS     ;set up pointer to output string
   MOV   AH,9       ;display string
   INT   21H        ;DOS call
   MOV   AH,30H     ;get DOS version number
   INT   21H        ;DOS call
   PUSH  AX         ;save copy of version number
   ADD   AL,30H     ;add ASCII bias to major version number
   MOV   DL,AL      ;prepare for output
   MOV   AH,2       ;output character to screen
   INT   21H        ;DOS call
   MOV   DL,'.'     ;load a period
   MOV   AH,2       ;output character to screen
   INT   21H        ;DOS call
   POP   AX         ;get version number back
   MOV   AL,AH      ;load minor version number
   MOV   BL,10      ;divide minor version number by 10
   SUB   AH,AH
   DIV   BL
   ADD   AL,30H     ;add ASCII bias
   MOV   DL,AL      ;prepare for output
   MOV   AH,2       ;output character to screen
   INT   21H        ;DOS call
   .EXIT

   END
```

Comment: ```;add ASCII bias``` - Hmmm, are you an electrical engineer?

Comment: I am studying for my B.S. in EET.

Comment: Hee, hee, I am so pleased with myself.  :)  Nothing wrong with your code or comment -- but my guess was that a person with a Maths or CS background would have written "offset."  ;)

Answer (score 1):

The version number you see at the top of the command-line interface, and which is returned by the `VER` command, is the Windows version, not the `DOS` version. As I understand it the Windows command-line interface is a DOS Emulator, rather than an actual instance of MS-DOS. It would appear that Windows NT based systems, which would include Windows 8, emulate a 5.0 version of MS-DOS (this seems to be suggested [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2711.htm) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS#Windows_command-line_interface)) - which would seem to be consistent with what you describe.

Comment: I see the issue... Windows 8 was released to manufacturing on 1 August 2012, with a build of 6.2.9200 (Yep, it's the Windows version).  Is there a command to display the DOS version?

Comment: From what I can see you're probably stuck with going with what you're assembly program provides.. Strictly speaking you're working in a DOS emulator, not an actual DOS environment, so the 'correct' version is what is returned from the `VER` command, and what you're int 21h, AX=30h is returning is the version of DOS which windows is emulating. From what I can see in some previous versions of Windows there were ways to get the 'emulated' version, but nothing seems to jump out for the more recent versions - although I'm happy to be corrected if there is a command to do this!